# Your site 'subdomain.domain.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, android-instant-apps, android-app-links

I have created an app link enabled android instant app. But while uploading app bundle to Instant App section in Play store I am getting error as,

***"Your site 'subdomain.domain.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app."***

I have uploaded assetlinks.json file generated from Android studio to the .well-known folder under that subdomain with sha256 fingerprint got from App Signing section in play store. 
I've verified those link via android studio and Statement List Generator and Tester(https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator). It gets verified in both.

**Verified that assetlinks.json file**

- is served with content-type application/json.
- accessible over an HTTPS connection
- accessible without any redirects (no 301 or 302 redirects) and can be accessible by bots

My AndroidManifest file

```xml
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="asset_statements" android:resource="@string/asset_statements" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="subdomain.domain.com" />
                <data android:pathPattern="/openapp" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="default-url"
                android:value="https://subdomain.domain.com/openapp" />

        </activity>
    </application>
```

**Please go through the screenshots,**

[Verified in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uw9Cy.png)

[Android App link tested in Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAngY.png)

[Asset links verified online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXiLZ.png)

[assetlinks.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fmIW.png)

[Error while upload instant app apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6cD4.png)

[App signing certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8N79k.png)

Comment: By looking at your manifest and screenshots I cannot spot any issues. I would file a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 for Google engineers to look more closely.